# Inequality with derivative and supremum norm

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

I have the following property written in a book but I can't understand why this implication is true. I would be glad if anyone could help me

let $A \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

$$\frac{d}{dt} \nabla A(x,t) = \nabla f(A(x,t)) \cdot \nabla A(x,t)$$
Then
$$\frac{d}{dt} |\nabla A(\cdot,t)|_0 \leq  |\nabla f(A(\cdot,t))|_0 \cdot |\nabla A(\cdot,t)|_0$$

I was thinking that maybe I could prove something like this:

If:
$$\frac{d}{dt} A = B$$
Then:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \mathrm{sup} |A| = \mathrm{sup}|B|,$$ then it would yield me the desired result

Comment: I find this is a bit hard to read. Maybe you could throw in a "suppose" somewhere, or just make it generally easier to read; it'll ultimately help you in attracting more attention to your question.